# DateTime class parameter should be const but DateTime does not support this

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

As seen in the screen shot the Flutter/Dart SDK is saying my optional parameter should be const. But the DateTime library does not support const constructors as seen in the Github link below.

What am I expected to do here to fix this besides not use a DateTime object type for this?

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/17014

[image]

Comment: This  is OK. Since DateTime.now() gives current time. and obviously having it as const doesn't make sense, as time changes every fraction.

Comment: You can use my [const_date_time](https://pub.dev/packages/const_date_time) package to achieve this.

```dart
import 'package:const_date_time/const_date_time.dart';

class MyClass {
  const MyClass({
    this.date = const ConstDateTime(0),
  });
  
  final DateTime date;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`.now()` named constructor can't be `const`.

You can use different parameter name and assign it in the constructor with null-aware operator(`??`) to add the default value with `DateTime.now()`.

You can read more about the null-aware operator [here](https://medium.com/@thinkdigitalsoftware/null-aware-operators-in-dart-53ffb8ae80bb).

Example:

```
class ExamlpeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final DateTime creationDate;
  
  ExamlpeWidget({
    DateTime creationDateTime,
  }) : creationDate = creationDateTime ?? DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you mind clarifying what `??` stands for in the answer for others? It's basically an OR operator from what I can understand when dealing with NULL values.

Comment: @IanSmith It's null check operator. Before assigning to creationdate. It says `creationDateTime` a question, ARE YOU NULL ? If it gives the answer as NO. Then the leftt side operand `creationDateTime` is assigned otherwise the right side `DateTime.now()`  is assigned to creationDate.

Comment: If `creationDateTime` is not null, it will assign it to `creationDate` else it will use `DateTime.now()`. I updated my answer with a link for article explaining what it does.

Comment: Getting error "All final variables must be initialized, but 'creationDate' isn't.
Try adding an initializer for the field."